# How to achieve build pipeline across multiple Jenkins master hosts?

Tags: git, jenkins, automation

I am trying to achieve a build pipeline across multiple environments. Lets say dev, qa , pre-prod and prod. But the problem is I have to achieve this build pipeline across two Jenkin's masters. One for dev and QA and one for pre-prod and prod. Lets say the Jenkins Masters as Master A and Master B.

let's say my job name is job1_dev which is pipelined(after successful build) to job1_qa. How can i achieve the pipeline for job1_preprod and job1_prod across two jenkins masters so that the pipeline is achieved

```
    job1_dev-->job1_qa (Jenkins master A)-->(Jenkins master B) job1_preprod-->job1_prod
```

Answer (score 2):

You could consider the [Parameterized Remote Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Remote+Trigger+Plugin) in order to trigger the preprod job on the second Jenkin master.

> A plugin for Jenkins CI that gives you the ability to trigger parameterized builds on a remote Jenkins server as part of your build.

That way, if `job1_qa` is successful, it can trigger `job1_preprod` on Jenkins master `B`.

> I don't want to start the job1_preprod automatically.., would like to use the artifacts/properties from job1_qa as the input for job1_preprod and would like to use them only if job1_qa is successful.

Create a *separate* `job_qa_success` which is triggered by `job_qa`, and which will call `job1_preprod` through that remote plugin: that `job_qa_success` will only run if `job_qa` is successfu

Comment: It was a good idea.., but i don't want to start the job1_preprod automatically.., would like to use the artifacts/properties from job1_qa as the input for job1_preprod and would like to use them only if job1_qa is successful.

Comment: @chanukyabachina then create a job_qa_success which is trigger by job_qa, and which will call job1_preprod: that job_qa_success will only run if job_qa is successful.

Comment: I want to use the properties from previous job but don't want to start it automatically... because we do multiple tests in dev and qa.. and don't want them to flow to preproduction and production environments. After job1_qa is successful, there is some manual testing involved...

Comment: @chanukyabachina any "manual" operation was not in your question. I tried to propose an implementation of a pipeline.